# Meta http-equiv, can I?

Tags: http, refresh, meta-tags

I have put this code in my index, to load a new page, and then later 2 secs later, move to my original screen.

With the intention to load a "music_player" and then 2 seconds later, move toward my NORMAL page.

Having the player load in a new window. But the code don't work as it should, it just replaces without the "Target="_blank" can't figure out why?

below is code !!

```
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
    <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="5; url=http://www.mysite.com/start.php" />
    <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="3;URL=http://www.mysite.com/player.html" Target="_blank/>
</head>
```

Comment: You've missed a quote after `_blank`.

Answer (score 2):

According to [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_meta.asp), target is not an attribute of the meta tag. If you want something like this, you should use javascript.

Answer (score 0):

The meta refresh method redirects the current page - it cannot be used to open new windows. For that, you'll need javascript `window.open`

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_open.asp

And `setTimeout` to delay it by 2 seconds:

http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_timing.asp

Answer (score 0):

The [`<meta>`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/global.html#edef-META) tag does not have a target attribute, so you can't use it to trigger a new browser window.

Answer (score 0):

If it's not working then it's probably because the `meta` tag doesn't accept the target attribute. You could try doing this with javascript:

```
<body onload="window.open(...);">
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like there are two problems. First, the second `http-equiv="refresh"` will have no effect, because the page will already have refreshed the first time.  If you wanted to refresh again, you'd have to put the second `http-equiv="refresh"` in the second page.  Second problem, `http-equiv="refresh"` isn't meant to open new windows.  You'll have to use Javascript (window.onload) for that, but be careful -- you'll run into popup blocker problems.

Basically you'll want:

1. First page loads, opens popup player window.
2. After, you forward to start.php (or you could just merge your first page with start.php, open the player window, and stay where you are at).